# access electron from spectron

Tags: angular, electron

I am working on  electron application and started with learning basic electron.

how to access electron app from spectron app installed on same machine?
how can I Access electron app from spectron app installed on different machines?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var Application = require('spectron').Application
    var app = require('electron')
    const path = require('path')

    var app = new Application({
      path: app,
      args: "../../myelectronapp"         //Path of your electron application 
    })

    app.start().then(function () {
      // Check if the window is visible
      console.log("Application started");
      return app.browserWindow.isVisible()

    }).then(function (isVisible) {
       // Verify the window is visible
       assert.equal(isVisible, true)

    }).catch(function (error) {
      // Log any failures
      console.error('Test failed', error.message)
    })
```